# How can i add a mobile-menu new mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

At the moment i only have a desktop Menu wich is also displayed on mobile devices. But my css and html don't fit for mobile because of the submenu and the Styling as such.
The current desktop menu looks like this:

```
<nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
    <?php
        show_menu2(
            $aMenu = 1,
            $aStart = SM2_ROOT,
            $aMaxLevel = SM2_ALL,
            $aOptions = SM2_ALL,
            $aItemOpen = '<li[if(class==menu-current){ class="current"}]>[a][menu_title]</a>',
            $aItemClose = '</li>',
            $aMenuOpen = '<ul>',
            $aMenuClose = '</ul>',
            $aTopItemOpen = false,
            $aTopMenuOpen = '<ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">'
        );
    ?>
</nav>

.srt-menu li a {
 transition: 0.3s ease;

 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;

 padding: 0px 0;
 margin: 0 0px;
 }

.srt-menu li li a {
background:#e8e8e8;
padding-left:40px;
}
.srt-menu li li li a {
background:#efefef;
padding-left:80px;
}

/*SECONDARY MENU*/
 #secondary-navigation{
margin-bottom:60px;
}
``#secondary-navigation ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#secondary-navigation ul li a{ 
background:pink;
display:block;
margin:5px 0; 
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}


/*colors and backgrounds*/
body{
    background:#fff;
}


/*** MAIN MENU - ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/


.srt-menu, .srt-menu * {
    list-style:     none;
}
.srt-menu ul {
    position:       absolute;
    display:none;
    width:          12em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.srt-menu ul li {
    width:          100%;
}

.srt-menu li {
    float:          left;
    position:       relative;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.srt-menu li li {
    margin-left:0px;
}
.srt-menu a {
    display:        block;
    position:       relative;
}



/*** DEMO1 SKIN ***/
#topnav, .srt-menu {
    float:right;
    margin: .35em 0 0 0;
}

.srt-menu li a {
    background:transparent;
    margin:0; 
    //padding:50px 50px;
    //height:45px;


   //background transparent;
    color:#195891;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-right:15px ;
    padding-left:15px;
    //margin: 25px 25px 25px ;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;


}
.srt-menu a, .srt-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    //color:            #1aa8a4;    
}



.srt-menu li a:hover{
color:#410CE8;
     box-shadow:  0px -8px 0px -2px #1aa8a4;
}

.srt-menu li:hover ul,
.srt-menu li.sfHover ul {

    display:block;
    left:           0;
    //top:          45px; /* match top ul list item height */
    //z-index:      99;
    //-webkit-box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px red;
    //box-shadow:  2px 3px 2px 0px red;
}

.srt-menu li.current a{
color:#2f86c4;
background:transparent;
}
```

How can i add a menu with the sandwich button when the menu is closed and an 'x' button when it's open, function: Closing menu. Like this one [here](http://codepen.io/sleepingKiwi/pen/xoaiq)

I'm a beginner and can't change coding on my own therefor it would be helpful if you could add an example based on the menu that already exists.

Comment: The link that you've postet won't work.

Comment: why don't you hire someone to do it for you?

Comment: I nearly made everything on my own and i would like to have some help because i thought that's what i get here, correct me if i'm wrong. Also i hoped that it's not such a big deal i just don't know how to do it.

Comment: @PatrickMlr Does it work for you?